# Why BlocBuilder is stuck in the initial state while using get_it?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I'm using [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) to manage the states of my app, and [get_it](https://pub.dev/packages/get_it) to inject the needed dependencies following the idea suggested by the [Reso Coder's Flutter Clean Architecture Proposal](https://github.com/ResoCoder/flutter-tdd-clean-architecture-course).

Everything is working fine except that the bloc is not changing its state (it's stuck in the initial state)

Here is the code of the involved classes:

**The States**

```
abstract class PaintingsState extends Equatable {
  final properties = const <dynamic>[];

  PaintingsState([properties]);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [properties];
}

class PaintingsLoading extends PaintingsState {}

class PaintingsLoaded extends PaintingsState {
  final PaintingCardItems cardItems;

  PaintingsLoaded({@required this.cardItems}) : super([cardItems]);
}

class Error extends PaintingsState {
  final String message;

  Error({@required this.message}) : super([message]);
}
```

**The Events**

```
abstract class PaintingsEvent extends Equatable {
  const PaintingsEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

/// Tells the bloc that it needs to load the paintings from the PaintingsRepository
class GetPaintings extends PaintingsEvent {}
```

**The Bloc**

```
const String FILE_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE = 'FileNotFound Failure';

class PaintingsBloc extends Bloc<PaintingsEvent, PaintingsState> {
  final GetPaintingCardItems getCardItems;

  PaintingsBloc({@required this.getCardItems}) : super(PaintingsLoading());

  @override
  Stream<PaintingsState> mapEventToState(PaintingsEvent event) async* {
    if (event is GetPaintings) {
      yield* _mapGetPaintingsToState();
    } 
  }

  Stream<PaintingsState> _mapGetPaintingsToState() async* {
    yield PaintingsLoading();
    final failureOrPaintingCardItems = await getCardItems(NoParams());
    yield failureOrPaintingCardItems.fold(
        (failure) => Error(message: _mapFailureToMessage(failure)),
        (paintingCardItems) => PaintingsLoaded(cardItems: paintingCardItems));
  }

  String _mapFailureToMessage(Failure failure) {
    switch (failure.runtimeType) {
      case FileNotFound:
        return FILE_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE;
      default:
        return 'Unexpected error';
    }
  }
}
```

**Dependencies injection**

```
/// Ambient variable to access the service locator
final sl = GetIt.instance;

/// Set up all the objects you want to access later through the service locator [sl]
void setUpServiceLocator() {
  initFeatures();
}

void initFeatures() {
  //! Features - Paintings
  // Bloc
  sl.registerLazySingleton<PaintingsBloc>(() => PaintingsBloc(getCardItems: sl<GetPaintingCardItems>()));

  // Use cases
  sl.registerLazySingleton<GetPaintingCardItems>(() => GetPaintingCardItems(sl<PaintingsRepository>()));

  // Repository
  sl.registerLazySingleton<PaintingsRepository>(
      () => PaintingsRepositoryImpl(dataSource: sl<PaintingsDataSource>()));

  // Data sources
  sl.registerLazySingleton<PaintingsDataSource>(() => PaintingsDataSourceImpl());    
}
```

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  // dependencies injection
  setUpServiceLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<PaintingsBloc>(
      create: (_) => sl<PaintingsBloc>(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My Paintings',
        theme: appTheme,
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Page where I use BlocBuilder**

```
class PaintingsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
       ...
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            SafeArea(
                child: Column(
                ...
                BlocBuilder<PaintingsBloc, PaintingsState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if(state is PaintingsLoading) {
                      return Container(
                        child: Center(
                           child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else if(state is PaintingsLoaded) {
                      List<PaintingCardItem> _list = state.cardItems.paintingCardItems;
                      return Expanded(
                            child: SizedBox(
                              child: _list.length != 0
                                  ? ListCardView(
                                      cardItems: _list)
                                  : Container(
                                      child: Center(child: Text('Empty list'))),
                            ),
                          );
                    } else if(state is Error){
                      return Container(
                            child: Center(child: Text(state.message)));
                    } else {
                       return Container(
                            child: Center(child: Text('Unknown Error')));
                    }
                  }
                )
              ],
            ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So, somehow the state of the bloc does not change from PaintingsLoading to either PaintingsLoaded or Error.

If someone can give me some idea to solve this problem, I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Where have you added the `GetPaintings` event to your bloc?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you asked me. Are you referring to the bloc file?

Comment: No problem. I'm saying where have you fired the event you wanted; Something like `yourBloc.add(GetPaintings());`.

Comment: Well, actually I didn't, but where should I do that? Should I add the event in the create parameter of the BlocProvider()? Something like `create: (_) => sl<PaintingsBloc>().add(GetPainting())`

Comment: Where ever you need that event to run; Like when a page is opened, when user taps on a button, etc. Yeah you could do sth like that with a little change though; `create: (_) => sl<PaintingsBloc>()..add(GetPainting())`. In create you should return an instance of a bloc that this way it will.

Comment: You are right, that works as well and at the same time, I just write less code :) and I don't need to change anything in the tests. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I just needed to add the event to the bloc. So, my solution was to create another state called PaintingsInitialState like so:

**The States**

```
...
class PaintingsInitialState extends PaintingsState {}
...
```

Then in the **Bloc**, I just changed the constructor of the bloc.

```
PaintingsBloc({@required this.getCardItems}) : super(PaintingsInitialState());`
```

Finally, I added the following condition inside the builder parameter of the BlocBuilder.

```
if (state is PaintingsInitialState) {
  _paintingsBloc.add(GetPaintings());
}
```

I think that the information provided in the [offitial site of the bloc library](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/) can be useful to understand how to use bloc pattern and libraries properly - particularly [Flutter Wheather Tutorial](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterweathertutorial).